# HowTo: Change "Material Design In Xaml" `ComboBox` behavior to only display dropdown when you click the arrow?

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

How do you modify the *Material Design In Xaml* (MDIX) `ComboBox`, so that it **only** displays the item list when the arrow button is clicked?  Is there an easy way to do this without breaking the library's behavior?

Any insight you can provide would be appreciated.

### Context

With a *.NET* `ComboBox`, the default behavior for a `IsEditable="True"` is:

- User clicks `ComboBox`, the list of available options ARE NOT displayed. <<< **desired behavior**
- User clicks `ComboBox` arrow, and the list of available options ARE displayed.

With a MDIX `ComboBox`, the default behavior for a `IsEditable="True"` is:

- User clicks `ComboBox`, the list of available options ARE displayed. <<< **undesired behavior**
- User clicks `ComboBox` arrow, and the list of available options IS displayed.

Attaching [SnoopWPF](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) shows that the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event is firing, but I hesitate to make any major changes (e.g. making my own copy of the resource) because I want to remain compatible with future versions of MDIX.

### Environment

- [MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit) project on GitHub
- Using [MaterialDesignThemes](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MaterialDesignThemes/4.0.0?_src=template) NuGet package v4.0.0-ci2347

  - Resource definition: [MaterialDesignTheme.ComboBox.xaml](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ComboBox.xaml)

Comment: @Reviewer: Rather than simply downvoting my question, could you please provide an explanation why? My post (1) has a clear question, (2) is not an opinion, (3) has references (4) includes an established StackOverFlow tag: material-design-in-xaml

Comment: This library has a Gitter chat: https://gitter.im/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit
 It's easiest way to contact with main contributor and others who use it - there you will find useful info.

Answer (score 0):

### Root Cause

I don't know if this was the original intent for the MDIX library, but it appears that:

1. the `toggleButton` is higher up in the visual tree than the `PART_EditableTextBox`
2. when you turn on `toggleButton` border you see that the Button takes up the entire width of the `ComboBox`

As a result, the `toggleButton` will always intercept mouse events.

### Solution

I finally found a solution: create a WPF attached property. This enables us to:

- have a behavior that is more like Microsoft's `ComboBox`
- while making it relatively easy to upgrade to future releases of the MDIX library

#### Source Code

The following attached behavior in XAML

```
<ComboBox materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasClearButton="True">
  <!-- implementation details here -->
</ComboBox>
```

uses this WPF attached behavior:

```
internal static class MdixComboBoxBehavior
{
        public static readonly DependencyProperty UseMicrosoftBehaviorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "UseMicrosoftBehavior", 
            typeof(bool), 
            typeof(MdixComboBoxBehavior), 
            new UIPropertyMetadata(default(bool), UseMicrosoftBehaviorChanged));

        public static bool GetUseMicrosoftBehavior(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(UseMicrosoftBehaviorProperty);
        }

        public static void SetUseMicrosoftBehavior(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(UseMicrosoftBehaviorProperty, value);
        }

        public static void UseMicrosoftBehaviorChanged(DependencyObject s, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (s is ComboBox comboBox)
            {
                comboBox.Loaded += OnControlLoaded;
            }
        }

        private static void OnControlLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is ComboBox comboBox)
            {
                if (comboBox.Template != null)
                {
                    if (comboBox.Template.FindName("toggleButton", comboBox) is ToggleButton button)
                    {
                        // Bug fix: the following makes the MDIX ComboBox 
                        // behave more like a Microsoft ComboBox. A list of options
                        // is only displayed when the user clicks the down arrow.
                        button.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
                        button.Width = 10;
                        button.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```